# How to merge with nested key in javascript spread operator?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following objects like

```
obj1 = { key1: { a: 1}}
```

I want to merge the following object with the above

```
key1 = { b: 2}
```

I want to get the result as following by merging the `key1` with the existing key in the first object.

```
{key1: {a: 1, b: 2}}
```

How can I do this using spread operator in javascript? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can spread both existing and new object

**Note:** Using spread operator will only merge the enumerable properties.

```js
const obj1 = { key1: { a: 1}}
const key1 = { b: 2};
const res = {...obj1,key1:{...obj1.key1,...key1}};
console.log(res)
```

If you want to modify the original object then only change `obj.key1`

```js
const obj1 = { key1: { a: 1}}
const key1 = { b: 2};
obj1.key1 = {...obj1.key1,...key1}
console.log(obj1)
```

Comment: Thanks Maheer. First one suits my situation well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the spread operator like so:

```js
let obj1 = {
  key1: {
    a: 1
  }
};

let key1 = {
  b: 2
};

obj1.key1 = { ...obj1.key1, ...key1 };
console.log(obj1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could splead it into the wanted property.

```js
var obj1 = { key1: { a: 1 } },
    key1 = { b: 2 };
    
obj1.key1 = { ...obj1.key1, ...key1 };

console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let obj1 = { key1: { a: 1}}

let b = { b: 2}
let a = obj1.key1; //{a:1}

// merge using spread operator
let key1 = {...a, ...b}; //{a:1, b:2}

obj1.key1 = key1; //{"a":1,"b":2"}

console.log(obj1) //{ "key1":{"a":1,"b":2"}}
```

Comment: What is the reason to use extra variables...why not directly change `obj.key1`

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Object.assign`

```js
var obj1 = { key1: { a: 1}};
var key1 = { b: 2};

Object.assign(obj1.key1, key1);

console.log(obj1)
```